# Insert date by datepicker into SQL through LINQ to sql in c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Hello i am working with LINQ to SQL.
I can insert data which retrieve from my windows form application in C#. 
but I can not retrieve "date" from "date picker" in windows form. 
How can i solve it. 
here's my code :

```
'  databaseDataContext reg_gur = new databaseDataContext();

        gurdian x =new gurdian()
        {
            name=name.Text.ToString(),
            username=username.Text.ToString(),
            password=password.Text.ToString(),
            gender=gender.SelectedItem.ToString(),
            dob=
```

in dob what should i write ??

thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to provide more information.  Are you just looking to get the date value from the datepicker or for a solution of saving that value to your database?  Perhaps posting some of your code will help.

Comment: exactly, 
i need a solution of saving that date value to save into my databse.

Comment: Assuming that you are using some sort of poco objects in your linq to sql, you would just have to set the date field value and save the entity.  Again, not seeing your code it's hard to give a solution.

Comment: ok sir, I add my code.

Comment: nope, its not work for me. 
In that solution is work with QUERY. 
but in LINQ TO SQL I can not insert data through Query.

Answer (score 0):

by using this i solve my problem :

```
   dob=datepicker.value
```